# AWS Comprehend NOT COMPLETED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, pii

I try to do COMPREHEND but immediately the command ends and the status remains as SUBMITTED
Does anyone know the problem and know how I can get the output?

[image: Amazon Comprehend execute]

I checked the job id status and got this:

[image: Amazon Comprehend output]

Comment: Please provide the listings as TEXT rather than images, to assist with searching and accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can check status of job on [describe-pii-entities-detection-job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/comprehend/describe-pii-entities-detection-job.html) with `job-id` from start job response.

Comment: thanks. Now I see that the status is FAILED  with the message "NO_WRITE_ACCESS_TO_OUTPUT", but I navigate the output to my folder

Comment: @imhere What do you mean by "I navigate the output to my folder"? The error message would suggest that Amazon Comprehend was not able to write the output to S3. Are you saying that the output _is_ available?

Comment: im not sure, how can I check if the output is available for that?

Comment: Error message is clear. The role you provided does not have permission to write output to bucket which you provided